# Where to put the ngIf?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, convention, angular-ng-if

I have a question about the ngIf of Angular 2. I'm currently developing my first bigger Angular 2-App and I'm wondering about the best positioning of the ngIf. I think that there should be a certain consistency. This are the three options I can think of, regarding to load a child-component:

> In a `div` of the parent-component:

```
<div id="parent-component-div" *ngIf="loadChildComponent">
  <app-child-component></app-child-component>
</div>
```

> In a child-component-tag of the parent-component:

```
<div id="parent-component-div">
  <app-child-component *ngIf="loadChildComponent"></app-child-component>
</div>
```

> In the child-component:

```
<!-- parent-component -->
<div id="parent-component-div">
      <app-child-component></app-child-component>
</div>

<!-- child-component -->
<div id="child-component-div" *ngIf="loadComponent">
      <!-- child-component logic -->
</div>
```

I personally, find my self following option one, but seeing advantages of option three. But what is the convention? Is there a convention?

Comment: Well it depends what you want to be disabled/hidden in your app. NgIf removes the DOM element completely so if you're sure you don't need your child component later on then it is safe to disable in the parent. If you thing you need to show it later on then do the hiding/removing part with ngIf in your child component. Remember that you can of course use also ngShow/ngHide if element is going to be used later on for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course highly subjective, but I believe that it should be put on the element that is shown or hidden based on some condition.

```
<div id="parent-component-div">
  <app-child-component *ngIf="loadChildComponent"></app-child-component>
</div>
```

We then may assume that this part of html is a template. So if you put `ngIf` on an element itself and we know how structural `ngIf` directive is transformed we end up with this DOM:

```
<div id="parent-component-div">
  <template [ngIf]="loadChildComponent">
      <app-child-component></app-child-component>
  </template>
</div>
```

which makes sense. If you put `ngIf` on the parent div like this:

```
<div id="parent-component-div" *ngIf="loadChildComponent">
  <app-child-component></app-child-component>
</div>
```

`parent-component-div` becomes part of a template and it doesn't seem like what you want to do.

The third option seems the least right for me since a component shouldn't care whether it's shown or not. If it's shown, then it should proceed with it's functionality.

Comment: Yes. I feel by now the same about option three. I started of with this option, but I feel less and less good with it.

Comment: @tschaka1904, yeah, consider what I've said about viewing ng-if content as a template, and you'll see that second option seems to be the best fit

Comment: @tschaka1904, also, consider accepting the answer if it helped :)

Comment: I think I have got a use case for the third option. I want to display loading indicator. And I have a parent with several children and they might have also some children. I can not be sure if all the child components are going to be loaded, because this depends on the current content you look at. Somehow, I need to tell my loading indicator that it can disappear again, because everything is loaded. Having this scenario, it might be worth loading each component and use my third option. But I might also be completely on the wrong path. Have you com across some similar scenario?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that where the ngIf goes depends a lot on who owns the variable ngIf is bound to.

If the setting of that loadComponent boolean is behaviour that belongs to the parent component, then you can go with option 2.

But if loadComponent really belongs to the child component, then option 3 makes more sense.